# Unity move arrows along path

Tags: unity, c#

I am not sure how to go about what might be a simple task. I want directional arrow sprites to move along a curved path in 2d to show the player when to go.

I can use DoTween to create a path. But not sure if I should Instantiate a load of sprites(arrow) and move them along. Its seems wasteful.

[image]

Comment: Did you consider doing this with a LineRenderer and a scrolling tiling texture?

Comment: Not I didn't actually. I looked it up and I don't see any examples unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory for that suggestion. I did more research and was able to get this working. If you want to add your suggestion as an answer I would be happy to mark it as the correct one.

Comment: If you have a working solution to your problem, then you'd be in an even better position to write it up as an answer — with screenshots and details of how you set it up to serve your needs. It's 100% OK to answer your own questions here. :)

Comment: I think it would be great if you added your own answer to this question, I could learn from it ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the following code I added to the `LineRenderer` to scroll the tiles texture.

```
public class LineArrow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float scrollSpeed = 1f;
    public Renderer _renderer;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _renderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float vOffset = Time.time * scrollSpeed;
        _renderer.material.SetTextureOffset("_MainTex", new Vector2(vOffset, 0));
    }
}
```